# Hue rotate in inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape, rotate

I have designed a background image in inkscape. But I used the wrong colour in the whole image or at least that's not feels good to me. So, in my website, I use `filter: hue-rotate(60deg)` to make it appear the right colour I want. But as filter the original image is a bit slower, I have decided to hue-rotate that in inkscape, but I can't find the option.

In case of rastered images like jpg, png, webp, ppm, etc. GIMP and other editors can do that well.

So how do I rotate the hue of an object to 60 degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Filters > Colour > Color shift*, and set the shift to 60°. Note that this is an SVG filter which may render differently in different browsers, or may also slow down rendering.

[image]

Or if you want to physically change the colours without using a filter, there's also *Extensions > Colour > HSL Adjust*. The Hue values are different from the Colour Shift filter and go from -360 to +360, so use a value of 30 instead of 60, but you may also have to tweak the lightness too.

[image]